# Relation between closed cone of curves of a small $\mathbb{Q}$-factorial modification of Mori dream space

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, birational-geometry

Let $X$ be a smooth projective variety which is a Mori dream space. Then we know there are finite small $\mathbb{Q}$-factorial modifications $f_i:X\dashrightarrow X_i$ for $i=1,\cdots,k$ such that $Mov(X)=\bigcup f_i^*(Nef(X_i))$. My question is
there a relation between $\overline{NE(X)}$ and $\overline{NE(X_i)}$ for each $i$?

Any comments, suggestions on how to think about the question will be extremely helpful.Thanks in advance!!

Comment: $\overline{NE(X)}$ is just the dual cone of $Nef(X)$, so you can just write down the correspondence in the dual space.